# (Java 11+) Should Class getResource URL for modules include /modules prefix?

Tags: java, module, resources

The URL returned from `Class.getResource` doesn't include `/modules` for module resources, but content can be loaded from the URL. However, when using nio the `FileSystem` expects `/modules` at the start of the path:

```java
URL url = String.class.getResource("String.class");
System.out.println(url); // jrt:/java.base/java/lang/String.class

try (InputStream in = url.openStream()) {
    in.readAllBytes(); // Success
}

Path path = Path.of(URI.create("jrt:/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class"));
System.out.println(path); // /modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class
Files.readAllBytes(path); // Success

path = Path.of(url.toURI());
System.out.println(path); // /java.base/java/lang/String.class
Files.readAllBytes(path); // NoSuchFileException
```

Is one of these approaches (`URL`/`Path`) incorrect? Seems like it would be good to have consistency across URIs.

Comment: Either of the first two is valid.  Of course, a `jrt:` URL will only work for classes in the Java SE runtime and not for your classes or any third party classes.  Personally, I would always use `getResource`.

Comment: @VGR A `jrt:` URL will also work for your own classes and third-party classes if the application is packaged by `jlink`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: For my use case I want to get directory listings within the module, so I would need to use Path. Looks like I need to get the URL and then manipulate it. Any idea why the URI schemes don't match?

Comment: @Slaw So it seems, though I’m not clear on whether that’s by design.  [JEP 220](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) says “…a new URL scheme, `jrt`, can be used to name the modules, classes, and resources stored in a run-time image…” I guess a jlink’d application qualifies as a single run-time image, but JEP 220 seems to use the term to refer to a JDK or JRE only.

Comment: @VGR The "run-time image" they talk about is, I believe, the `<java-version>/lib/modules` file. When you use `jlink` all the modules you link are put into a custom-built `.../modules` file. Maybe that's why it works (and would _seem_ by design)?

Comment: @Slaw I agree that is why it works, but I’m still not sure whether it’s by design.  Though a jlink’d image is in some ways a customized Java runtime.  I think there are a lot of aspects of jlink that are not as well documented as they could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the inconsistency has been fixed in JDK13b23:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8216553